# Direction of the particle's motion

Tags: waves, kinematics

[image]

```
^ y
|
| 
|--------------> x
```

Above I have labelled the axes of the graph.

In the figure we can see that the direction of the particles motion is downward when the displacement is going to increase. Why is that?

Comment: When the particle is displaced downwards, then the motion is downwards... Can we agree that the full line is the current position and the dashed line is the next position? Then all arrows do point in the correct direction; in the direction of *displacement*.

Comment: Comment to the question (v3): Note that the horizontal axis denotes a spatial direction $x$, not time $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say *displacement*, do you then mean displacement of each *particle*? Or the displacement of the *wave / wavetops*?

I guess the latter. If this is a rope being swung to create the wave motion, then remember to keep a sharp distinction between *particle motion* and *wave motion*. As the particles in the rope move up and down (*transverse*) the wavetops are moving sideways.

There is nothing wrong with your figure. If the arrows show the direction of motion of the particles, then you must compare this to *particle* displacement, not *wave* displacement. And the *particles* all move from their current position (on the full line) to another position above or below (on the dashed line); that is, they move to the spot on the dashed line *vertically above or below* them.

And since all arrows point from full to dashed line, this seems to fit together nicely.